# Unknown argument `pinned`. Available options are listed in green

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma, remix.run

I have the following Prisma model:

```
model Thread {
  id         Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  authorId   String
  subforumId Int
  createdAt  DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt  DateTime  @updatedAt
  title      String
  content    String
  pinned     Boolean   @default(false)
  deleted    DateTime?
  posts      Post[]
  author     User      @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  subforum   Subforum  @relation(fields: [subforumId], references: [id])
}
```

But my `seed.ts` getting the following error while running `pnpm prisma db seed`:

```bash
Unknown argument `pinned`. Available options are listed in green.
    at Ur (D:\Sandbox\forumix\node_modules\.pnpm\@prisma+client@5.1.1_prisma@5.1.1\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:115:5852)
    at Hr.handleRequestError (D:\Sandbox\forumix\node_modules\.pnpm\@prisma+client@5.1.1_prisma@5.1.1\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:6698)
    at Hr.handleAndLogRequestError (D:\Sandbox\forumix\node_modules\.pnpm\@prisma+client@5.1.1_prisma@5.1.1\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:6388)
    at Hr.request (D:\Sandbox\forumix\node_modules\.pnpm\@prisma+client@5.1.1_prisma@5.1.1\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:6108)
    at async l (D:\Sandbox\forumix\node_modules\.pnpm\@prisma+client@5.1.1_prisma@5.1.1\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:126:10298)
    at async seed (D:\Sandbox\forumix\prisma\seed.ts:74:5) {
  clientVersion: '5.1.1'
}

The seed command has been executed.
```

`seed.ts` file:

```
const db = new PrismaClient();

await db.thread.createMany({
  data: [
    {
      title: "Registro de Oficios",
      content: "¿Qué hace tu personaje?",
      authorId: admin.id,
      subforumId: 1,
      pinned: true,
    },
    {
      title: "Registro de PBs",
      content: "Revisa este tema antes de elegir un físico para tu personaje.",
      authorId: admin.id,
      subforumId: 1,
      pinned: true,
    },
    {
      title: "Sistema de Combates",
      content: "Este tutorial te mostrará todo lo necesario para combatir en el foro.",
      authorId: admin.id,
      subforumId: 2,
      pinned: true,
    },
    {
      title: "Economía",
      content: "¿Cómo funciona el sistema económico del foro? Acá te explicaremos todo lo referente a ello.",
      authorId: admin.id,
      subforumId: 2,
      pinned: true,
    },
    {
      title: "Misiones",
      content: "Este tipo de rol te permitirá ganar experiencia y dinero.",
      authorId: admin.id,
      subforumId: 2,
      pinned: true,
    },
    {
      title: "Arruina el deseo",
      content:
        "Debes responder a este tema pidiendo un nuevo deseo luego de arruinar el deseo de arriba. Deseo cantar como un famoso!",
      authorId: marySue.id,
      subforumId: 3,
    },
  ],
  skipDuplicates: true,
});
```

package.json's seed script:

```json
"db:seed": "ts-node --require tsconfig-paths/register prisma/seed.ts"
```

What's going on there?

Comment: What database are you using? Postgres, etc. Also, what happens when you remove the pinned column in your data? Have you tried just one row?

Comment: @Kiliman I'm using postgres. I've tried one row, yes. Same error. Removing the column works just fine. Thing is, this column IS present in the database. I just can't seed data in it.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76882403/10431732 "

Documentation of Prisma says : you cannot use the createMany function with nested relations directly. Instead, you should use the create function in a loop to achieve this. Below an example"